# For each loops and Offsets

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, foreach

I am developing a code in VBA and I am having trouble with a task that searches a range in one worksheet for a string; then records the string in the same row but left one column (so .offset(0, -1)) for all occurrences; then it searches for each recorded string in another worksheet and sums the integers corresponding to the recorded strings to the right of the column.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub StoredProcTimes()
    Worksheets("Proc Time").Select
    Dim Table() As Variant, nItem As Integer
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Name = "ProcTime"
    nItem = Range("ProcTime").Rows.Count
    ReDim Table(nItem, 2)
End Sub

Public Sub DayLoad()
    Range("G2", Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Name = "Dates"
    Call StoredProcTimes
    Dim reply As Date, cell As Range, sum As Integer
    reply = InputBox("Specify Date", "Day Load", "9/1/2017")
    For Each cell In Range("Dates")
        If cell.Value = reply Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "The load for " & reply & " is " & sum & " minutes"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: This sounds like it can be done with a SUMIFS or SUMPRODCT function, does this have to be VBA?

Comment: Now,  please explain the nature of the error and on which line you get the error.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on cell.offset, now that i have the desired values I am confused on how to search for them in another worksheet

Comment: Have you tried using Find?

Comment: Yes, I am trying the find function, but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

For one, your line `cell.Offset(0, -1).Value` isn't doing anything. You didn't set it equal to a value. You should be receiving an error here.

It's my personal preference not to use `Offset()`, but it's not necessarily a big deal *to use* it. In my example, I am showing you an alternate method that I find is favorable.

And for your specific cell that you are trying to find, don't loop through the range, this takes processor time. Use `Range.Find()`.

```
Public Sub DayLoad()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngG As Range

    ' You may need to change the index, or use "SheetName"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rngG = ws.UsedRange.Columns("G")

    'Call keyword is unnecessary 
    Call StoredProcTimes

    Dim sReply As String, myCell As Range
    sReply = InputBox("Specify Date", "Day Load", "9/1/2017")
    If Not IsDate(sReply) Then Exit Sub

    ' Search for your date
    Set myCell = rngG.Find(sReply)

    ' If date was found, then copy the date to the left 1 col
    If Not myCell Is Nothing Then
        With myCell
            ws.Cells(.Row, .Column - 1) = .Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; after you have copied the value left of the cell, would you store it as a variable and search the other sheet for the value?

Comment: @WillParker It's already stored as a variable, `sReply`. You can use that if you need to search another sheet as well.

Comment: Would sReply not be the response to the inputbox, i.e. the date? sReply = InputBox("Specify Date", "Day Load", "9/1/2017")

Comment: In your last line you're using the undeclared variables `reply` and `sum`.

Comment: @WillParker It is the response to the input box, and it's also the value you are asking about. Why create another variable if the variable of your value already exists? Just because you used your variable once doesn't inhibit your ability to reuse it again. // Thanks Fernando.